# Parsing JSON in ruby?

Tags: json, ruby

I have following json:

```
[{"test": "test_a", "doc_type": { "id": 32 }}]
```

So I am trying to parse it, but I am receiving error which is

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String.

Sorry I am learning Ruby :D
This is the code.

```
obj = JSON.parse(j)
```

Comment: As shown it's an array containing a single hash (w/ a nested hash); there's no need to parse it. `JSON.parse` expects a string, not an array. For it to be JSON it'd need to be a string.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the comment. I am expecting something like this: [{"test": "test_a", "doc_type": { "id": 32 }}] from API which returns json like this. So when i parse it, there should not be error right?

Comment: `JSON.parse('[{"test": "test_a", "doc_type": { "id": 32 }}]')` works as expected, and you get an Array out of it. Given your error, it seems that your json was already parsed by the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse() expects a string input. So, array can't be used here.
Instead you can try as follows,

```
JSON.parse('[{"test": "test_a", "doc_type": { "id": 32 }}]')
```

Or

```
JSON.parse(arrayResponse.to_json)
```

to_json returns JSON string representation. Doc: https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_json

Answer (score 2):

The data structure in your post is not a JSON string that can be parsed but it is a Ruby array containing a hash.

If it was a JSON string then parsing would work:

```
JSON.parse('[{"test": "test_a", "doc_type": { "id": 32 }}]')
#=> [{"test"=>"test_a", "doc_type"=>{"id"=>32}}]
```

But if you try to JSON parse a Ruby array then you get exactly the error you describe:

```
JSON.parse([{"test": "test_a", "doc_type": { "id": 32 }}])
#=> no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)
```

That probably means that the library you use to load the JSON automatically parses it to a Ruby hash.

Comment: "Ruby hash" -> "Ruby array (which contains a hash)"

Comment: But if it was already a Ruby hash, it wouldn’t have JSON-style quoted keys upon inspection. Maybe the OP copied the JSON result from the API into Ruby manually?

Comment: @Stefan technically what was posted is not a ruby inspection representation of a `Hash` at all as it would either be `[{"test" => "test_a", "doc_type" => { "id"=> 32 }}]` or `[{:test => "test_a", :doc_type => { :id=> 32 }}]`